# How can I tell if the current TCP segment is part of a large PDU

Tags: networking, tcp, pcap

I'm writing a small application using `libpcap`, where I parse/analyze a `TCP` based application. I faced a situation, where application attempts to send a really large amount of data, say 64K, and `TCP` layer cuts it into a number of smaller segments.

Now, my question is -- how do I really tell that a TCP payload of the packet, read from `pcap`, is actually a chunk of a larger payload. So, in order to access original large payload, number of segments will need to be re-assembled.

TCP header has sequence field, but I don't fully understand how it can answer my question.

Also, IP header has `total_length` field, but it has nothing to do with TCP segmentation, it indicates IP payload size of the *current* packet.

I'd appreciate to get some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't agree with your title. Segments are not parts of larger segments, but packets are.

Comment: Because TCP segments streams of data, you must reassemble the segments to get the data. You may have an application-layer protocol, e.g. HTTP, that has PDUs.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for comment. Do you mean that TCP segments are just reassembled irregardless? Because my question was - how do I _tell_ that I have a small segment that has to be reassembled in a large packet.

Comment: Yes, TCP segments form a stream of data. They are _not_ individual application messages. One segment could be several application messages or several segments could be an application message. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP can't help you here because it neither knows nor cares what PDUs are. You need to implement whatever protocol defines what a "large PDU" is. For example, if this is HTTP over TCP, implementing the HTTP protocol will tell you if the segment is part of a large PDU.

> Because my question was - how do I tell that I have a small segment that has to be reassembled in a large packet.

That's what a message protocol is for. If, for example, the message protocol says that a PDU is a "series of characters not containing a newline character terminated by a newline character", then if you don't have a newline character, you know it's part of a larger PDU.

The concept of PDUs applies to message protocols, so if you're talking about PDUs, you must have a message protocol. The message protocol will tell you when you have an entire PDU. That's its purpose.